# Create a new empty list in an a list of lists

Tags: java, list

What I'm trying to do with this code is that it gives the user a choice between 2 items in a list and the selected item is taken to a new list in the list of lists. I just wanted to know if the implementation of my new list creation is correct or no. I have another non related bug in the program so I can't test if the implementation works or not.

```
public static void compareTwo(List<List<String>> list){
       int result;
        for (int j = 0;j<list.size();j++) {
            if ((list.get(j).size() / 2) % 2 == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.get(j).size(); i = +2) {
                    String x = list.get(j).get(i);// gets stuff inside the inner list
                    String y = list.get(j).get(i+1);
                    System.out.println("1 ("+x+") or 2 ("+y+")" );
                    result = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());

                    list.add(j + 1, new ArrayList<String>() {
                    });// add another inner list to biglist

                    list.get(j+1).clear();//clears the new inner list

                    if (result==1){
                        String z = list.get(j).get(i);
                        list.get(j+1).add(z);
                    }
                    else{
                        String z = list.get(j).get(i+1);
                        list.get(j+1).add(z);
                    }


                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.add(j + 1, new ArrayList<String>() {
});// add another inner list to biglist

list.get(j+1).clear();//clears the new inner list
```

This is creating an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`: unless you've got a good reason to do that, don't. Also, you don't need to clear a newly-created `ArrayList`, it's already empty.

As such, you can reduce this code to:

```
list.add(j + 1, new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll do that. Can you explain what "This is creating an anonymous subclass of ArrayList" means? I'm kinda new to this programming thing

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

I can see two serious problems in your code:

1. Since the following line is trying to access value at index `i + 1`, the `for` loop must be `for (int i = 0; i < list.get(j).size() - 1; i = +2)` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. In your code it is, `for (int i = 0; i < list.get(j).size(); i = +2)`.

```
String y = list.get(j).get(i+1);
```

2. In the following line, you are not handling exceptions for the cases when the user enters a non-integer value.

```
result = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
```

It should be like

```
boolean valid;
do {
    valid = true;
    try {
        result = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("This is not an integer. Please try again.");
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Apart from these two serious problems, the second line in the following code snippet doesn't make sense as there is no element to clear in the newly added inner list

```
list.add(j + 1, new ArrayList<String>() {});// add another inner list to biglist    
list.get(j+1).clear();//clears the new inner list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this version for simplicity and readability

```
List<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(j + 1, inner);
```

, or some java's double-brace initialization

```
list.add(j + 1, new ArrayList<>(){{ 
  add("hello"); 
  add("world");
}});
```

Comment: "java's hidden feature" This isn't a hidden feature, it's a syntactic abuse called [double-brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java), and should be approached with great care.